# Proving that supremum of set is infinity

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, elementary-set-theory, proof-verification, supremum-and-infimum

I've come into trouble while trying to prove that $\sup\left\{n^2 + n + 1 \mid n \in \mathbb{N} \right\} = +\infty.$

While first statement of supremum is apparent i.e. $(\forall n \in \mathbb{N})(n^2 + n + 1 < +\infty)$, I can't come up with idea, how to prove the second one $(\forall \alpha \in \mathbb{R}, \alpha < +\infty)(\exists n \in \mathbb{N})(n^2 + n + 1 > \alpha).$

My try is based on fact, that because there is exists quantifier, I can chose some fixed $n$ which will then accomplish $n^2 + n + 1 > \alpha$. So if someone gives me $\alpha < +\infty$ which is a fixed number, I'm taking $n = \left \lfloor{\alpha}\right \rfloor + 1$.

Is my approach correct?

Comment: $n^2+n+1=(n+1/2)^2+3/4>(n+1/2)^2>n+1/2>n$

Comment: @Moya: Why did you have to do all those manipulations? Wasn't it obvious that $n^2 + n + 1 > n$ simply because $n^2 + 1 > 0$?

Comment: @AlexM. Of course, I just went with the first thing I thought, but that's probably because I don't see obvious things like that.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**

$$n^2+n+1\geq n$$
for all $n\geq 1$.

Comment: And now the OP will ask why $\sup \{n \mid n \in \Bbb N \} = +\infty$...

Comment: @AlexM.: You don't need to be a genius to prove this ! Indeed, if $M>0$, don't we have that for $N=\lfloor M\rfloor$ that $n>N\implies n>M$ ?